# cakephp - Call to undefined method EmailComponent::send()

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to cakephp, I looked at other answers but couldn't find a solution. I am trying to send an email after registration. But it shows undefined method error. Below is my code

```
public $components = array(
        'Email',
        'Session',
        'Auth',
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        //'Security',
    );
```

AppController

```
function send_email($process = "",$replace_fields=array(),$replace_with=array(),$email_template=null,$to=null,$extraTemplate = null)
    {

        // Loaded EmailTemplate Model
        $this->loadModel('EmailTemplate');
        $template=$this->EmailTemplate->find("first",array("conditions"=>array('EmailTemplate.alias'=>$email_template)));

        //  Used for Custom Templates
        if ($extraTemplate != '')
        {
            $template_data = $extraTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            $template_data=$template['EmailTemplate']['description'];       
        }

        $replace_fields = array_merge($replace_fields, array('{logo}'));
        $logoSrc = HTTP_ROOT.'img/front/logo.png';

        $replace_with = array_merge($replace_with, array($logoSrc));
        $template_info=str_replace($replace_fields,$replace_with,$template_data);
        $template_info=str_replace(HTTP_ROOT,'/maheswarDev/',$template_info);
        $template_info=str_replace('/maheswarDev/',HTTP_ROOT,$template_info);

        //print_R($template_info); die;

        // SMTP Options
        $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
            'port'=>"25", 
            'timeout'=>'30',
            'host' => 'mail.mindstack.in',
            'username'=>'my-email',
            'password'=>'my-password'
        );

         // Set delivery method
        $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
        $this->Email->SMTPAuth = true;
        $this->Email->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $this->Email->charset  = 'UTF-8';
        $this->set('data',$template_info);
        $this->Email->to = $to;
        $this->Email->subject = $template['EmailTemplate']['subject'];
        $this->Email->from = $template['EmailTemplate']['from'];
        $this->Email->template = 'email_template';
        $this->Email->sendAs = 'both'; 


        $this->Email->send();

        // Check for SMTP errors.
        $this->set('smtp_errors', $this->Email->smtpError);
    }
```

Comment: Have you added `App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');` to the controller?

Comment: @b0s3 yes still the same :(

Comment: please visit this link http://svikramblg.blogspot.in/

Comment: i followed the tutorial, and i get "From is not specified" even thought i have $Email->from = 'my-email' :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Email` component](http://api.cakephp.org/2.1/class-EmailComponent.html) has been deprecated so you should use [`CakeEmail`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html) instead.

Make sure you load the class either at the top of your controller or where you are about to use it:-

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

You then need to create a new email object:-

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
$Email->to($to);
$Email->subject($template['EmailTemplate']['subject']);
$Email->from($template['EmailTemplate']['from']);
$Email->template('email_template');
$Email->emailFormat('both');
$Email->viewVars(['data' => $template_info]);
$Email->send();
```

You define the email connections similar to databases in your `app/Config/email.php` file:-

```
class EmailConfig {
    public $smtp = array(
        'host' => 'mail.mindstack.in',
        'port' => 25,
        'username' => 'my-email',
        'password' => 'my-password',
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'tls' => true
    );
}
```

The first parameter of `CakeEmail()` determines which email configuration to use. As of CakePHP 2.7 to use the `$default` configuration you can just create an email object like:-

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
```

Comment: thanks, some progress but it shows "From is not specified", even though i have mentioned from email $Email->from = 'my-email' :(

Comment: Sorry, my example code was in correct (typed it out too early in the morning for me). The configurations are done as methods rather than properties. I've updated my answer.